# Razor Pages - Foreach loop through list to get data to display on razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I can't get the data to display on the razor view. I am currently getting the data and filling my object in the **DataAccessLayer.GetData()** function. My objects list gets filled and stored. However my objects list count is 0 on the razor view therefore it shows nothing. Am I **"newing"** up my Object correctly on the view? This is the first time using the razor pages template so it's a learning curve.

**Razor Page:**

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="GetData">
    <input id="txtSearch" name="search" />
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-dark" id="btnSubmit" name="Submit" />
</form>


@{ List<ObjectsModel> objects = new List<ObjectsModel>();

    @foreach (var record in objects)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => record.COLUMN1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => record.COLUMN2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => record.COLUMN3)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

**PageModel:**

```
 public class ObjectsModel : PageModel
{
    public string COLUMN1 { get; set; }
    public string COLUMN2 { get; set; }
    public string COLUMN3 { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public void OnPostGetData(string search)
    {

        List<ObjectsModel> objects = new List<ObjectsModel>();

        DataAccessLayer.GetData(search, out objects);
        return;
    }
}
```

**DataAccessLayer:**

```
public class DataAccessLayer
    {
        public static bool GetData(string ID, out List<ObjectsModel> objects)
        {
            string connectionString = "";
            objects = new List<ObjectsModel>();

            try
            {
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                command.CommandText = @"SELECT top 50 COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
                                         "FROM Table";


                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ObjectsModel item = new ObjectsModel();                
                    item.COLUMN1 = reader.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim();
                    item.COLUMN2 = reader.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim();
                    item.COLUMN3 = reader.GetValue(2).ToString().Trim();

                    objects.Add(item);
                }

                    reader.Close();
                    reader = null;
                    command = null;         
                    connection.Close();
                    connection = null;

                    return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                exc.ToString();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Am I "newing" up my Object correctly on the view?"  It would appear not - you're constructing a brand new list in your view, which is of course empty.  You need to reference the list you constructed and added to in your PageModel.

Comment: So I am referencing ion the OnPostGetData handler method. The problem is I can't reference the objects list on the view side because "it does not exist". How can I access the list without creating a new list in the view?

Comment: Your code is wrong on many places, you are not sending a model to your View at all, GetData populates wrong List, you already have public List defined in your class. It looks like you skipped some tutorials... first try to send List<string> to your view model before you include database

Comment: @Djuro I see what you're saying. Let me make some changes, read over some more documentation and I will update the code!

Comment: @Djuro I have updated the code. I took out the public List in the model class and am now just generating it in my Data Access.GetDataFunction(). The list is being filled, and I can see the count is 50 on the view page when debugging. However it changes to 0 when continuing through. I know it's because I am a creating a new List on the view page. How can I initialize that list without it generating a new instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this section of code

```
@{ List<ObjectsModel> objects = new List<ObjectsModel>();

    @foreach (var record in objects)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => record.COLUMN1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => record.COLUMN2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => record.COLUMN3)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

to this

```
public class ObjectsModel : PageModel
{
    public string COLUMN1 { get; set; }
    public string COLUMN2 { get; set; }
    public string COLUMN3 { get; set; }

    public List<ObjectsModel> objects{get; set;}

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public void OnPostGetData(string search)
    {

        DataAccessLayer.GetData(search, out objects);
        return;
    }
}



@{ 

    @foreach (var record in Model.objects)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => record.COLUMN1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => record.COLUMN2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => record.COLUMN3)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I made the changes. However, it is now saying Object  Reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: This was close but I needed to instantiate the objects List in my ObjectsModel in order to access it in my Razor Page. I posted an answer below that shows exactly what I did. +1 and accepting this as answer since you pushed me in the correct direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by adding my objects List property into my Objects Model and initializing it there rather than on the view page. I no longer need a reference in the Razor View as I can access the list in the my loop with @Model.objects. Obviously I have changed the name of my page model and properties since this will be a live project in production eventually.

**Updated PageModel:**

```
 public class ObjectsModel : PageModel
{
    public class Object
    {
        public string COLUMN1 { get; set; }
        public string COLUMN2 { get; set; }
        public string COLUMN3 { get; set; }
        public List<ObjectsModel> objects = new <ObjectsModel>();
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public void OnPostGetData(string search)
    {    
        DataAccessLayer.GetData(search, out objects);
        return;
    }
}
```

**Updated Razor Page:**

```
@{

    @foreach (var record in @Model.objects)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => record.COLUMN1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => record.COLUMN2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => record.COLUMN3)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```